# Angular 2 build fails, Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>' despite explicit rxjs import

Tags: angular, rxjs

For the past two days we are getting the following error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'
```

While trying to build one of our components (on server). Build works fine locally (running the same build scripts, installing clean npm dependencies).

I've seen similar errors reported on older versions of Angular (beta) but nothing seems relevant (there are some work arounds suggested, but I'm trying to avoid them)

Did anyone run into similar problems? Any ideas what might be causing this?

We are explicitly importing rxjs map at the top of the file:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Which was suggested in a few similar questions - it does not solve the problem.

Angular is version 2.0.1

Comment: I've tried importing rxjs directly (import "rxjs/add/operator/map";) with no luck

Comment: Okay, retracted my flag ;) Hopefully someone can help, I can't think of anything :(

Comment: Cheers. We are running tests atm, might be todo with Yarn messing with us, will post update when I get final results

Comment: Whenever something works locally and fails on a build-server I usually check the case of filenames: Windows is not sensitive to case in file-names, while linux is resolving filenames and directories case-sensitive

Comment: Can you check what `rxjs` you have installed on the server? For example with `npm ls --depth=0`.

Comment: moving from Yarn to NPM fixed the problem, we are still investigating the cause, but the assumption is that Yarn installed a different version of some dependency. I'm closing this up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem was due to problem with Yarn installing a different version than npm - we are still investigating which dependency was acted out.